# Cleanest way to format a String

Tags: java

I'm trying to format a phone number which is stored without formatting in a database.
Now currently I just use substring and String concatination to form the formatted String but I'm looking for a cleaner/faster/less memory intensive method. (and I don't mean just using a StringBuilder).

I looked at String.format but that only takes a list of parameters (as in ...) and not a chararray.

Comment: Is this a bottle-neck in your program?

Comment: I smell some premature optimization.  Ten bucks says that a profiler will point elsewhere in the program.

Comment: I'd say that string manipulations are resource wise insignificant compared to database access.

Comment: Thanatos: No it isn't, however it's not so much about being slow/resource optimization as in I like to learn cleaner way to do things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll toss in my 2 cents after some lookup:

```
import java.swing.text.MaskFormater;

try {
    MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("+AA AAA AA AA AA");
    formatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
    System.err.println(formatter.valueToString("31987365414"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
```

}

Comment: This is simpler than using a StringBuilder, but I'll eat my hat if this is faster or less memory intensive :-)

Comment: True, a StringBuilder is probably slightly faster especially since the MaskFormatter also uses a StringBuffer behind the screens and contains more logic. But a MaskFormatter is easier to maintain/change than a StringBuilder. Especially if I were to put the mask in a properties file. So the MaskFormater also offers increased flexibility. Besides, the real slowdowns are elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a `String` from char array(s) plus some things (chars,  strings, whatever) between them, then `StringBuilder` is definitely the right way to go, if you don't want to simply concatenate. An important point is to initialize the builder with enough initial capacity so that it doesn't need to reallocate its internals while building.

Comment: Actually I have a String (say 31987365414) and I need to format it so it resembles: +31 987 36 54 14. That's why I was hoping there was a way to format that cleanly. I just saw that swing has a maskformatter, but that class doesn't seem to work entirely on my pc. (or it just needs a reboot)

Comment: If you don't have `MaskFormatter`, then I expect that you are using an ancient Java SE, or Java ME or Android or some such.  The class has been in Java SE since 1.4.

Comment: I have the class, my compiler just crashed on it but a reboot fixed it.